# HTML5 Time Element in Form with Milliseconds

Tags: html, forms, validation

There are several examples of HTML5 form options on [this](http://cdn.sixrevisions.com/demos/0345-new_html5_form_input_types/new-html5-form-input-types.html) page, including the "time" element. Is it possible to force the time element to include a millisecond component?

I'm not concerned for the fallback option where a plain text box is used.

Comment: At http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.datetime.html#input.datetime-attributes it says is uses http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3339#section-5.6 to define it's date/time format and this doesn't include milliseconds so I doubt any browser will user milliseconds on `<input type="datetime-local">`. You may want to checkout the `<time>` element https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time but be sure to check the supported browsers as it is almost none.

Answer (score 17):

This works:

```
<input type="time" step="0.001"></input>
```

Live preview: http://jsbin.com/giqikelumu/edit?html,output

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the step attribute. In case of a input type="time". The step attribute defaults to 60 (1 means 1 second). But you can also set fractions.

```
<input type="time" step="any" />
```

Comment: That does not work in Chrome.  When I set a ngModel in angular to a new Date() it displays milliseconds.  I tried step="1", step="1000" with same results.  Which makes sense to me as this should be step size for up down arrows and not a controller for accuracy.  To my brain anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As its an input tag, the value can be entered into it by the user then using the step attribute as stated above will surely help.
What if this input is in the form and value can come from some API cal and is given to the form to show it. It can be changed too. If the requirement then is to show or not show the second or millisecond part we can do the following.

### When second and millisecond is required

```
getFormatDate = function (val) { // assuming val is date like "/Date(946673340000)/"
 if (val != undefined) {
        date = new Date(val.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1); // creating a date object from val
        return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 
date.getHours(), date.getMinutes(), date.getSeconds(), date.getMilliseconds());
    }
}
```

### When second and millisecond is **NOT** required

```
getFormatDate = function (val) { // assuming val is date like "/Date(946673340000)/"
 if (val != undefined) {
        date = new Date(val.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1); // creating a date object from val
        return new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate(), 
date.getHours(), date.getMinutes());
    }
}
```