# Rails time field's value key not rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails

According to the documentation for the time_field, you can define the format in the object's value, like "%T.%L" in order to allow input of milliseconds.

in my view I have:

```
.field
  = f.label :start
  = f.time_field :start, value: "%T.%L"
```

The input tag renders as:
[image: screen shot of input time field]

I also tried it this way:

```
f.time_field :start, value: "%H:%M:%S.%L"
```

but that too rendered the same way.

Documentation is sparse though:
https://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/time_field

Answer (score 0):

This isn't part of the Rails form helpers documentation; rather, I found it as part of the HTML5 inputs itself:

[HTML5 Time Element in Form with Milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21127366/html5-time-element-in-form-with-milliseconds)

So I modified my own code to be:

```
f.time_field :start, step: 0.001
```

And it renders this way:
[image: Screenshot of time input rendering with milliseconds]

Only have to remove that PM part, but from what I can tell it's just a matter of CSS for that part.